# Concatenate strings for matrix from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, pivot, crosstab

I have 3 tables in my PostgreSQL database, implementing a many-to-many relationship: `droit`, `role` and `role_droit`. See diagram in the attached image. I have this query to return the current result (also in the image):

```
SELECT matrix_view.droit_id,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 1 then haspair end) as  "role A" ,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 2 then haspair end) as  "role B" ,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 3 then haspair end) as  "role C" ,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 4 then haspair end) as  "role D"
from (
        SELECT allRD.aid as aid, allRD.droit_id, max(case when RD.role_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasPair
        from (
                select distinct a.role_id as aid, b.droit_id as droit_id
                from role a cross join droit b 
             ) as allRD 
        left outer join role_Droit RD
        on allRD.aid = RD.role_id and allRD.droit_id = RD.droit_id
        group by  allRD.droit_id,  allRD.aid
        order by  allRD.aid
    ) AS matrix_view
group by matrix_view.droit_id
order by matrix_view.droit_id
```

I would like to show a concatenation of `id_droit`, `id_role` and `haspair` in intersection between `droit` and `role`! The **desired result** is also in the image:

[image: Sample data and result]

Comment: For future reference: we very much prefer data as *text* over images. One cannot copy / paste an image to run tests ... And please always disclose your Postgres version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a pivot / crosstab problem. But since you want results for a small, given set of roles, we can take a shortcut:

```
SELECT droit_name
     , droit_id || ',1,' || EXISTS (SELECT FROM role_droit WHERE droit_id = d.droit_id AND role_id = 1)::int AS "role A"
     , droit_id || ',2,' || EXISTS (SELECT FROM role_droit WHERE droit_id = d.droit_id AND role_id = 2)::int AS "role B"
     , droit_id || ',3,' || EXISTS (SELECT FROM role_droit WHERE droit_id = d.droit_id AND role_id = 3)::int AS "role C"
     , droit_id || ',4,' || EXISTS (SELECT FROM role_droit WHERE droit_id = d.droit_id AND role_id = 4)::int AS "role D"
FROM   droit d
ORDER  BY droit_id;
```

Produces your desired result precisely.

I provided role name and ID manually, since you only want results for the given roles, and number and names of columns cannot be changed dynamically in SQL anyway.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=95db4a8e1a50553c859f346bffdef702)*

Answer (score 0):

Notice that: You use fixed numbers for Roles (`"role A" , "role B" , "role C" , "role D"`) in your query and I used them too.

Try below query:

```
SELECT cast(matrix_view.droit_name as text),
    matrix_view.droit_id || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 1 then matrix_view.aid end) || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 1 then haspair end) as  "role A" ,
    matrix_view.droit_id || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 2 then matrix_view.aid end) || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 2 then haspair end) as  "role B" ,
    matrix_view.droit_id || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 3 then matrix_view.aid end) || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 3 then haspair end) as  "role C" ,
    matrix_view.droit_id || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 4 then matrix_view.aid end) || ',' || sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 4 then haspair end) as  "role D"

from (
        SELECT allRD.aid as aid, allRD.droit_id,allRD.droit_name , max(case when RD.role_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasPair
        from (
                select distinct a.role_id as aid, b.droit_id as droit_id , b.droit_name as droit_name
                from role a cross join droit b 
             ) as allRD 
        left outer join role_Droit RD
        on allRD.aid = RD.role_id and allRD.droit_id = RD.droit_id
        group by  allRD.droit_id,  allRD.aid ,allRD.droit_name
        order by  allRD.aid
    ) AS matrix_view
group by matrix_view.droit_id, matrix_view.droit_name
order by matrix_view.droit_id
```